# Create Object in Azure Analysis Service using REST API call

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

Is it possible to create Azure Analysis service Objects using REST API call? In other words, can I execute below like TMSL scripts through REST API Call in order to create Database, Table, and Partitions?

```
{  
  "createOrReplace": {  
    "object": {  
      "database": "AdventureWorksTabular1200",  
      "table": "FactSalesQuota",  
      "partition": "FactSalesQuota - 2011"  
    },  
    "partition": {  
      "name": "Sales Quota for 2011",  
      "mode": "import",  
      "dataView": "full",  
      "source": {  
        "query": [  
          "SELECT [dbo].[FactSalesQuota].* FROM [dbo].[FactSalesQuota]",  
          "JOIN DimDate as DD",  
          "on DD.DateKey = FactSalesQuota.DateKey",  
          "WHERE DD.CalendarYear='2011'"  
        ],  
        "dataSource": "SqlServer localhost AdventureworksDW2016"  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

What I have found is, it supports Model Refresh and Sync operation only. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware this is not possible.

Per the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions) your options are within SSMS, via Powershell or via SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Rest API documentation, there is a method to deterine the current available operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/operations/list

[image]